# Unable to upload DSYM file on fabric?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

Hello I have got the folder of all DSYM from archive of a build.Now i am trying to upload all the DSYM file as zip file but get this error.I have also tried to upload a single DSYM file as zip but still getting the error.

[image]

I have followed the steps from here https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#bitcode-download.but still no success

Below are my generated DSYM files.

[image]

- I have tried uploading all files a zip folder
- I have tried uploading DSYM file as zip folder

Please tell me what is the issue ?

[![enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: can you show some additional images

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: i dont ask this , i asked your image not clear to understand ple enlarge the omage or

Comment: now check added full image'

Comment: You need to compact your DYSM folder complete and upload de zip file, note that you have missings DYSMS from several versions

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Try using the upload-symbols script in a terminal. For example: /Applications/Fabric.app/Contents/MacOS/upload-symbols -a YourAPIKey -p ios /Users/mbonnell/Documents/PathToDSYM

Replace the API key and path with actual values and that should output more information on why the dSYM can't be processed.

Comment: @deepakkumar - your problem is solved or not bro

Comment: Not yet still having issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanku Mike for letting me know.

Try using the upload-symbols script in a terminal. For example:

**`/Applications/Fabric.app/Contents/MacOS/upload-symbols -a YourAPIKey -p ios /Users/mbonnell/Documents/PathToDSYM`**

> **PS:** Replace the API key and path with actual values and that should output more information on why the dSYM can't be processed

Above solution worked for me.

Comment: I have tried this solution. In terminal it shows successfully submitted, but on fabric.io it is still showing missing dSYMs